# Auto layout - Replace origin of one UILabel with other

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have two `UILabel`'s. One `UILabel` is on the top of other. What I want is, if there is no content in top one, the bottom one should take the origin of top.
**I have to use Auto Layout on the screen**. I tried using `sizeToFit` but that is not working. Bottom `UILabel` is still stuck at it's origin if there isn't no content in top `UILabel`.

Comment: please set outlet for constraint  and try

Answer (score 1):

Setting constraint for height will not work. The y position of second label will not get its correct Y axis value (It will shift upwards). I **solve your problem** by playing with `vertical spacing constraint` between two results.

Explanation:- Set the normal basic constraints for label plus vertical spacing constraint. When there is no text in upper label, then update the vertical spacing constraint as follows:-

```
verticalSpacingConstraintBetweenLabels.constant = -(KIntialVerticalSpacing + (KHeightOfLabel-KIntialVerticalSpacing));
```

[image]

I create a `sample project` for you. **Source code** is available at:-
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/eq9hinnw4sdfltq/LabelSpacing.zip?dl=0](http://www.dropbox.com/s/eq9hinnw4sdfltq/LabelSpacing.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to that requirement is to make IBOutlet for the height of the upper label and set it to 0 whenever you don't want to show it. But keep in mind you have to set vertical spacing between upper and lower label. The lower label shouldn't have top margin to superview.

Answer (score 0):

First drag both top constrains to UIViewController.
Second paste this code:

```
-(void) loadLabels{
    _firstLabel.text=@"";
    NSInteger heidFirstLabel = 20;
    if(_firstLabel.text.length == 0){
        _constrainTopFirstLabel.constant = 0 - heidFirstLabel;
        _firstLabel.hidden = YES;
    }else{
        _constrainTopFirstLabel.constant = 8 ;
    }
}
```

I always use this.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS9 apple has introduces a new class [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) to solve this and other problems that we the developers were facing, using auto layout. If you are targeting iOS 9 and later, you should use this class.

If you are targeting versions before iOS 9, one of the many ways could be using intrinsic content size.

1.Subclass `UILabel`

2.Add a property that determines if this label is collapses or not

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isLabelCollapsed;
```

3.Override its method intrinsicContentSize

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    if(self.isLabelCollapsed)
        return CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    else
        return [super intrinsicContentSize];
}
```

4.Set you collapsable labels class as your custom class.

5.When needed, set your `isLabelCollapsed` property to `YES` and call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on you collapsble label.